# get hourly finance info with yahoo finance -> hourly numbers not available anymore?

Tags: python, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get hourly stock data from yahoo finance, the code is simple:

```
import yfinance as yf
from datetime import datetime, date

tickerData = yf.Ticker('AAPL')
today = tickerData.history(start = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.min.time()), period = '1h')
print(today)
```

I was using the page as a reference: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/66043/yfinance-incoherent-daily-and-hourly-values

One that page the user has a '1h' period which delivers hourly stock data. However, in my code I am getting the error: `AAPL: Period '1h' is invalid, must be one of ['1d', '5d', '1mo', '3mo', '6mo', '1y', '2y', '5y', '10y', 'ytd', 'max']`

Did yahoo finance change something or is the hourly stock data only available behind a paywall?

Comment: Isn't it the interval, not the period? `today = tickerData.history(start="2023-02-17", interval='1h')`